# Does Citrus Pay provide a REST api?

Tags: rest, citrus-pay

I want to integrate Citrus Pay payment gateway. I did some google search whether Citrus Pay provides REST api, but I couldn't find Citrus Pay provides a REST api, instead it provides a web-kit named [Citrus.js](http://citruspay.com/DevelopersGuide/index.html#/citrusjs). But I want to integrate to it using REST api, if provided.

Can any one guide me in this regard?

Comment: Did you complete to integrate the citrus coding

Comment: Hi Ram, The REST API integration is provided to only PCI DSS compliant firms. You might want to integrate citrus.js provided by citrus which does a similar job for you.

Answer (score 0):

As of today Citrus doesn't provide Rest API for Payment gateway integration, however add-on products are totally based upon REST APIs.